# How to search a range of dates between another range with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm pretty new to using Laravel, but I've managed to create a pretty basic API. I'm starting to try and add filters to the API, and the primary filter I need is to see if a date range overlaps another date range.

For example, here is a typical data object returned from my database:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'This is the name',
    start_date: '2017-01-03',
    end_date: '2017-01-29'
}
```

The users would typically filter by a smaller date range. For example, give me results whose start and end range fall between 2017-01-28 and 2017-02-04.

So something like:

```
data start                data end
    |------------------------|
        |----------------|
   search start      search end
```

Throughout my research, I can only find answers relating to searching if a single date falls in a range, not if any part of a range falls inside another range.

This is what I currently have:

```
$closures = Closures::where('start_date', '>=', $from)->where('end_date', '<=', $to)->get();
```

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't really account for partial overlaps. In the above example, my search date is indeed greater than or equal to the data's, but since the end date is actually greater than the data's end date, it will not be returned.

The obvious would be to make the second stipulation and `orWhere`, but then that returns literally all data with a less than date which does not work.

I basically need to check if any part of of my search range falls within the data's range. Is this even possible, if so, any ideas on how I could achieve this.

Comment: What makes you think that having the end date be greater than the maximum end date in the data set will prevent it from being returned? The query doesn't care what the max date is when doing the comparison, and should work just fine.

Comment: If the user is searching for an end date that is greater than the end date of the data the `<=` clause will not be satisfied and therefore not return the data. User enters 2017-02-04 which is not less than or equal to 2017-01-31, so it will not return.

Comment: That logic could be read in English as "give me records where the end_date is less than or equal to 2017-02-04". Since "2017-01-31" is indeed less than that date, it WILL return unless the start date condition is AFTER 2017-01-31. If it is not working, then there is something else amiss.

Comment: Sorry, you're right in this case, the end date is not the issue, the start date is.  Show me record where the start_date is greater than or equal to 2017-01-28 is not satisfied because the date of the data's start is 2017-01-03.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would check to see if any of the 2 dates provided falls between a range in your data.  I would use nested wheres to avoid any logic spill over.

```
$closures = Closures::where(function($query) use ($start) {
    return $query->where('start_date', '<=', $start)->where('end_date', '>=', $start);
})
->orWhere(function($query) use ($end) {
    return $query->where('start_date', '<=', $end)->where('end_date', '>=', $end);
})
->get();
```

Comment: This was perfect. I had to modify a bit in terms of comparators, but this is exactly what I was looking for!